# Trouble save some data from infinite while loop in Python:

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to make a script which will find a coordinate of the cursor on the screen and save it if user do some action for example (doubleclick or press some key) but I have no idea how to save something from infinite loop and do it by action. Moreover how then to finish infinite loop. Here's
my code:

```
import pyautogui as pag
import time

while True:
    print(pag.position())
    time.sleep(1)
    if pag.doubleClick():
        x = pag.position()
```

Comment: Im not sure pyautogui is the correct package for what you are trying to do. Seems you are after an event listener for mouse clicks. [This could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688871/how-to-detect-if-mouse-was-clicked#53144008)

Answer (score 0):

I did it, just in a different way. I made a function which did the same task, showing the cursor position. I would like to do it by infinite loop saving current cursor position after click. But I can't understand is it possible to save data in infinite loop by some action. And I would like to make click the input in my function, which will show current cursor position but I also don't know how to make click an input. If you will find some other, better solution I will be happy to see it.
import pyautogui as pag

```
def find_position():
    cursor_position = input("Click to know the position of your cursor: ")
    if cursor_position == "click":
        print(pag.position())
    elif cursor_position == "exit":
        exit()
    else:
        print("You didn't click")
    find_position()


find_position()
```