# Python winrt module: MouseDevice is not activatable

Tags: python, winapi, windows-runtime

Using winrt module with Python, I was attempting **to capture mouse click event**. I was unable to find an example in resolving my problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.input.mousedevice?view=winrt-22621

Otherwise, do I utilise a different class to obtain the above information?

So, far I have this code below, is there a way for accomplishing my above objective?
`

```
import winrt.windows.devices.input as iwinrt
v = iwinrt.MouseDevice()
print(v.get_for_current_view)

Result:
v = iwinrt.MouseDevice()
TypeError: MouseDevice is not activatable`
```

**Expected Result Pseudocode:**
`

```
while(True):
   if(v.mouse_clicked):
       //Do something
       break
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if mouse was clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688871/how-to-detect-if-mouse-was-clicked)

Comment: Maybe try using [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput) instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I want to utilise the winrt Microsoft's package, I know the other libraries could achieve the result, I was just concerned about who manages those third party libraries unlike Microsoft.

Comment: And also, is not winrt module superseding win32api?